# Google Analytics not registering clicks

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a website that has some Google Analytics (GA) code and I wanted to track the downloads made to one file on my site, I googled for a while and found that if I added this code:

```
onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/descarga_programa_Mono');"
```

I could track the downloads by just looking at the "descarga_programa_Mono" that would appear on the GA dashboard, however I am not getting any results =/ is there something I'm missing?

My GA code is the newest one as far as I know the one that starts with:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

and it's before the onClick script that I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement,
if you want to make an virtual pageview in a specific button, you can do this way:

```
<a href="Link to Facebook"
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/click/facebook/button', 'location.href']);">
<img src="myButtonName"></a>
//Using location.href, you will know in wich page the user was when he was redirected.
```

Any questions, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

By using **onclick** (all lowercase) the browser already understands you are using JavaScript.
So that **javascript:** on your code is unnecessary.
That would be necessary on the **href** attribute of an **a** tag.

That **pageTracker** object you have found is related to the SYNCHRONOUS ga version. NOT the one you are using.
Use _gaq.push() instead as Bruno Brandão pointed out (although, on his example, there shouldnt be slashes around **location.href**).

The position (**head** or **before body end**) of the **ga script** does not matter as it is loaded and ran before the user can click something, independently.